# How can I use Google Maps functions in Vuex's createStore()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-maps, vuex

I am trying to set up my Vuex store states to contain an array of Marker objects from Google Maps Javascript API. Currently, my createStore function looks like this:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
    
export default createStore({
  state: {
    GCPMarkers: {
      basemapMarkers: [new google.maps.Marker()],
      mosaicMarkers: [new google.maps.Marker()],
    },
  },
  // other properties
});
```

The Google Maps Javascript API is loaded in a Vue component named Map in my Home page:

```
// In Map.vue
mounted() {
  const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: "my key",
    version: "weekly",
  });
    
  loader
    .load()
    .then(this.initMap)
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
},
```

And my main.ts is like so:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

When I run my app, it reports the following in the `basemapMarkers: [new google.maps.Marker()],` line:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

I understand that the error is due to `google` not being loaded yet by the time that `import store from "./store"` is ran. However, I'm not sure what the right approach to solve this problem is.

The best I could come up with is moving the loader code to my main.ts so that only when the promise from `loader` is resolved do I start importing other files. However, that feels clunky to me and is probably not the way.

Comment: I guess it depends on the `google` dependency is it a npm package or from a cdn ?

Comment: The `Loader` that I used to load the API is from an npm package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need `google` to be defined (loaded by `Loader`), you should defer the app creation until *after* `Loader` has completed. Assuming the `load()` succeeds in assigning the `google` global, you could create the app in that `Promise`'s callback:

```js
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "my key",
  version: "weekly",
});
    
loader
  .load()
  .then(() => {
    const store = require('./store').default
    createApp(App)
      .use(store) // ok to use store now that `google` is loaded
      .mount('#app');
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: FYI: `Loader` refers to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader